# Constructible numbers lie in a field of degree power of 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am stuck with the proof of this. The following is known:

1. I can construct $\mathbb{Q}$.
2. I can only construct $\sqrt n, <n>$ given $n$

Therefore, the proof says, I can **only** construct numbers algebraic of degree power of 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$, since for any real number $\alpha$ to be constructible, there exists a sequence of fields, 
$$ \mathbb{Q} =F_0 \subset F_1 \subset ... \subset F_k \ \ \ (1)$$
and $F_i = F_{i-1}(\sqrt {\alpha_i})$.

**However**, it is still not clear if $\mathbb{Q}$ is the only base field I can construct. In other words, the given condition is rewritten as:

1. $F(\sqrt \alpha) \subset F$
2. $\mathbb{Q} \subset F$

where $F$ is the field of constructible numbers. But as far as I can go, I can only prove the numbers in $F_k$ in equation (1) are constructible, but not all constructible must reside in some $F_k$.

Comment: You have some unit length available from the start, and from that essentially the only algebraic operations you can perform through construction (using compass and unmarked straightedge) are addition, subtraction, multiplication and division (giving you all of $\Bbb Q$ and only $\Bbb Q$) as well as square roots (giving you any extension of degree $2$, repeated as necessary to get any extension with degree a power of $2$). What exactly about this is it you aren't certain about?

Comment: Thx, I think you made it more clear to me indeed. How about this, all constructible numbers are the results of algebraic operations that only include unit length, and any finite many algebraic operations take you into field with degree a power of 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this using induction on the number of operations needed to construct . First, suppose the numbers in the set $X_k$ = {$x_1,...x_k$} have been constructed.

We want to prove: if $x_{k+1}$ is constructed from points with coordinates in $X_x$, then [Q($x_{k+1}$) : Q($X_k$)] = 1 or 2.
Then, we know that $x_{k+1}$ can be constructed using 5 operations:
1) Draw a line through 2 existing points 
2) Draw a circle center at a constructed point, with radius equal distance between 2 constructed points 
3) Mark a point of intersection between two lines 
4) Mark an intersection(s) of line and circle 
5) Mark intersection(s) of two circles 
 
Then, for each of these operations, you show that $x_{k+1}$ - the new point - is the root of either a linear or quadratic equation whose coefficients lie in $X_k$. And there you have it, because each new point extends the existing field by only order 1 or 2, any constructible number lies in an extension field of degree $2^n$ for some n i.e. in your language, every constructible reside in some $F_k$.

Comment: Indeed, it is clear that I get to construct all the extension (of degree powers of 2) of $\mathbb Q$ once I constructed $\mathbb Q$. But my point was I was not sure if $\mathbb Q$ was the only base field I can construct, because the way of constructing $\mathbb Q$ seems rather intuitive than inductive.